# Will we ever be able to embed private soundcloud songs?

Tags: feature-request, soundcloud

I think it would be really cool if we could embed private soundcloud songs. Soundcloud does give you the option to embed private songs and also gives you a "secret link" option. I didn't know this didn't work until trying it a few weeks ago.

Will this ever be available?